# Car hands free not connecting with Ubuntu Phone bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, phone

I have just received my Ubuntu phone and I'm a little disappointed to see that it is not being recognised my the car's hands free system (Mazda3 2014 model). I never had any issues connecting my Samsung GS5 before - so it's not a car issue. I use my phone in the car extensively.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please [edit] your question and add the make and model of your phone as well as the output of `rfkill list all`. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek The BQ Ubuntu Edition phone is the only production phone released so far with Ubuntu on it. People have started receiving them over the past few days, so expect to see more phone related questions as more people get them, and have questions. :)

Comment: Have had the same problem - looks like it's a known issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1435040

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect the BQ Ubuntu Phone to my built-in handsfree set (Volvo V60, 2014) by turning the car in discoverable mode and connecting to the car from the phone.

Vice versa, i.e. connecting to the phone (in discoverable mode) from the car did not work. In my other car (Volvo V50, 2010) neither method works.

Comment: I installed the latest Ubuntu phone software update yesterday, but despite a number of tries today, it still didn't connect.